Rails authentification fails after server update
I have an application running Rails 4.1. It was running fine, but our IT updated the server infrastructure (basically migrating from Debian 8 to Debian 11) and since then the authentication no longer works.
I'm not really an expert in Ruby/Rails and I tried to figure out why it is now broken, but here is what I know. I hope someone could help me.
After the server upgrade, I had to change in the app configuration database (database.yml) : encoding utf8 to latin2. I have no choice on that. From there, the app is OK except the authentication.
The point of failure is in the session_controller defined like :
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!, only: :create

  def create
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])

    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      user.update_attributes authentication_token: Devise.friendly_token
      sign_in user

      data = {
        user_token: user.authentication_token,
        user_email: user.email,
        user_id: user.id
      }
      render json: data, status: 201
    else
      render json: {errors: "invalid email or password"}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  ...
end

The variable user is correct, but user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])returns always false and the following error is thrown in the log :
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity

Removing the test && user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password]) allows the user to login (danger of course). Updating a user's password throws this error:
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash)

related to this line : @user.update_attributes(sanitizer)
If anyone has any clue about that, I would really really appreciate.

I don't know if changing the db encoding would invalidate the password digests but it is something that could be repoduced locally.

Also even if the app is "running fine" Rails 4.1 is ancient and it's huge security vulnerability. It would be wise to discuss plans to either upgrade or retire the app.

Thanks. Yeah, we know this app end of life is near. It is completelly internal so security is somewhat okish…

user is correct. I can debug it and it returns #<User id: 17, name: "John", …. The valid_password returns falseyou are right (I forgot the .inspect in the log)
I also suspected an issue with the digest. But have no idea about the solution. How can I update digests?

More investigations : if I bypass the valid_password? condition, I can login. From there if I update the user's password, I get :
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash)

Did you consider switching back to utf8?
